# Remove Nulls from multiple lists in list

Tags: r, list, null

I have a big list (`A`) of lists of SpatialPolygonsDataFrames. Some of the lists have null values (means there is no SpatialPolygonsDataFrame). I tried :

```
A[!sapply(unlist(A, recursive=FALSE), is.null)]
```

But with no result and then I tried:

```
A_nonulls=lapply(A, na.omit)
```

What is the right way to remove the null of every list in the bigger list?

EDIT:

I can't do str(A)because A has 1000 lists and is huge. The first elements from the first list is like :

```
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
NULL

[[5]]
class       : SpatialPolygons 
features    : 1 
extent      : 722951.5, 726848.9, 4325874, 4329654  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

So I want to removw the nulls and keep only the not empty elements.

Comment: Maybe `A[!vapply(A,is.null,TRUE)]`?

Comment: nicola I tried but nulls are still in lists

Comment: Try `Filter(Negate(is.null), A)`

Comment: You must be more specific. Some `NULL` went away? Some remained? Do you have nested lists? With your specific example my line (as the @akrun's one) works.

Comment: @akrun thank you that works for me!

Comment: @nicola for some reason for me the A[!vapply(A,is.null,TRUE)] doesn't work. I will try it again to find why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try `Filter`

```
Filter(Negate(is.null), A)
```

Answer (score 6):

another option using Hadley's terrific **purrr** package:

```
library(purrr)
compact(A)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
A[!sapply(A, is.null)]
```